# How to Download my MYSQL Backup?

Tags: mysql, ftp, download, backup, filezilla

Okay I use this script here to make a backup of my database:

```
mysqldump -u root -h localhost -pPASSWORD forums | gzip -9 > backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql.gz
```

This is used in a `cron` daily.

But I need to download this remotely or through a ftp program every day as well so I have a physical copy of it on my home hard drive, is this possible? I know it is, can anyone tell me a quick way  to do it?

Comment: I do the same but email the file to a GMail account

Comment: Yeah, I do that too but it only works up to 25 Megabytes :( Unless I do not use gmail? What mail service do you recommend? Thanks

Comment: is your home machine running an ftp/sftp server? if not, then your home machine would have to actively reach out to grab the file.

Comment: How about uploading to Dropbox? http://www.andreafabrizi.it/?dropbox_uploader

Comment: @MarcB Nope so I was wondering how could I actively reach out via via maybe windows scheduler or something? I could setup the sftp server on my home network if you can link on a good tutorial maybe.

Comment: If you can run ruby, please check https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup gem. It has a lot of features.

Comment: mysqldump --user=root --password=PASSWORD forums | gzip |  ncftpput -c -u root -p PASSWORD 76.121.167.17 backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%s).sql.gz


I found a fix, i just opened port 21 on my modem and turned on DMZ Hosting :) Thank you @MarcB!!!!

Make sure NCFTP is installed :)

Comment: @NiCkNewman It'd be good if you put that as an answer, and close the question :)

Comment: It wouldn't let me because I am a new user or something :(  I will do it now..

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump --user=root --password=PASSWORD forums | gzip | ncftpput -c -u root -p PASSWORD 76.121.167.17 backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%s).sql.gz I found a fix, i just opened port 21 on my modem and turned on DMZ Hosting :) Thank you @MarcB!!!! Make sure NCFTP is installed :)